# React-Native - lifting state up in functional components

Tags: react-native, functional-programming, components

I am trying to share the state from child components to parent component , not using state management , all the components are functional components , how can I do that without using state management like redux or context API ? I have checked the listing state up all the the examples and documentation are in class components , please help me with the same ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sharing state between components is really all about prop drilling, that is to say, passing props a parent component receives to its child component. Because props are passed on with JSX there is minimal difference between prop drilling in a functional component and a class component.

The biggest difference would be at the top level component where the state and its modifier function are passed to the first child component. This difference  is very trivial, e.g

```js
// accessing state variable and state modifier in class component
<CustomComponent
  user={this.state.user}
  setUser={
    newUser=>this.setState(prev=>({...prev,user:newUser})
  }
/>
// accessing state variable and state modifier in functional component
<CustomComponent
  user={user}
  setUser={setUser}
/>
```

Even so, this react [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context) gives a basic example of efficient prop drilling that uses functional components